# Require Helpers Module File in Grape API

Tags: ruby, module, helper, grape-api

This is the structure of my Grape API.

```
app
|  /api
   |   /v1
   |   application.rb
   /helpers
   |   warden_helpers.rb
   /models
   |   user.rb
```

This is my warden_helpers.rb file;

```
require 'grape'
require 'warden'

module WardenHelpers
    extend Grape::API::Helpers
    # Helpers go here
end
```

And this is how I am trying to require them in `application.rb`;

```
require 'grape'

# Load files from folders
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/app/api/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/app/helpers/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    helpers WardenHelpers
  end
end
```

If I include the helpers as a block in `application.rb` or place the module in the same file - everything works fine. But this approach throws an error: `in '<class:Root>': uninitialized constant API::Root::WardenHelpers (NameError)`

Answer (score 2):

namespace WardenHelpers in Helpers module

```
module Helpers
   module WardenHelpers
    extend Grape::API::Helpers
    # Helpers go here
  end
end
```

than use `helpers Helpers::WardenHelpers` in `application.rb`